# Bundle and Access a file within the BlackBerry PhoneGap / Cordova file system

Tags: file, sqlite, cordova, blackberry

I am building a BlackBerry application using Cordova / PhoneGap. My end-goal is to be able to bundle a pre-populated SQLite database with the application.

I have seen a few tutorials that suggest including the desired file in an Assets folder and loading it on first app-load.

In order to achieve the end of a pre-populated database, I am going to want to access the local file system on the blackberry device.

Using the samples provided in the Cordova documentation I've put together the following:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    var fail = function(err){console.log(err)};
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
        function(fs){
            var reader = fs.root.createReader().readEntries(
                function(entries){
                    console.log("FS:"+entries)
                },
                fail);
        },fail
    );
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///store/home", 
        function(uri){
            console.log(uri);
        }, 
        fail);      
}
```

In all cases, the file list is empty on the simulators (trying with the chrome ripple plugin specifically)

```
missing exec:File.resolveLocalFileSystemURI ripple.js:39
["file:///store/home"] ripple.js:39
TypeError
 ripple.js:39
TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports.resolveLocalFileSystemURI (chrome-    extension://geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc/ripple.js:39:7398)
    at module.exports.exec (chrome-    extension://geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc/ripple.js:39:19386)
    at module.exports (http://telusbb.com/cordova-2.3.0.js:9602:5)
    at app.onDeviceReady (http://telusbb.com/js/index.js:73:10)
    at Channel.fire (http://telusbb.com/cordova-2.3.0.js:690:23)
    at http://telusbb.com/cordova-2.3.0.js:219:47 ripple.js:39
File ripple.js:46
    resolveLocalFileSystemURI 
 FS:
```

I am unable to figure out from the documentation, where I want to store a file for it to appear in the PhoneGap filesystem.

Currently my assets folder is in `<sampleapplciation>/www/assets` is there another path I should be storing files in if I wan to access them within the app?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option will be to build your pre-packaged SQLite DB outside the package, and then using an INSERT query, build the DB on first launch of the app.

I'm doing this (granted, with a very simple DB) in one of my iOS Phonegap apps.  It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Might be irrelevant but I believe the Ripple issue is related to the location of your file on your computer.
By the way I would suggest you use WebWorks SDK, it's pretty awesome with lots of native API access, maybe the IO api will help you in what you need plus it's pretty straight forward to package and install using both Ripple or Command Line (debugging on the device is excellent too with Web-inspector enabled devices).